# Is it possible to make the bot respond to a message that has one of the elements in an Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, discord, discord.js, bots

I am trying to make my Bot I am currently developing able to respond to a message, Which i really did it.

However I want the bot to respond to one of the elements/strings in an Array, so i don't have to repeatedly write `(message.includes('example')) || (message.includes('example2'))`.
I tried doing this with an **if statement** as that is the only way i know how to. :

```js
client.on('message', message =>{

    if (message.author.bot) return;

    const fixgreet = message.content.slice();
    const greetings = fixgreet.toLowerCase();
    const gnvars = fs.readFileSync('./commands/urls/gn.txt').toString('utf-8');
    const gnraw = gnvars.split('\n');

    if (greetings.includes(gnraw)) {
        client.responds.get('gn').execute(message, fixgreet);
    }
```

Which doesn't return an error at all, but also won't respond.
`gnraw` is the Array which contains the elements, and `greetings` is the message content sent by the user, the if statement should be true when the message content contains one of the elements in `gnraw` and it should send a response.

gn.txt is a TEXT file with strings, which i created it into an array (`gnraw`) by using :

```js
const gnvars = fs.readFileSync('./commands/urls/gn.txt').toString('utf-8');
const gnraw = gnvars.split('\n');
```

Here is an example of what would they look.

the TEXT file could be:

```
gm
good morning
good day
```

Then `gnraw` will be `['gm', 'good morning', 'good day']` which is formatted from the TEXT file.

As an example of what i would like to happen.

User A : "Good morning." *sends a message, which then identified as `greetings`

User B : "GM" *identified as `greetings` aswell.

if one of the elements in `gnraw` is included in `greetings` then
the Bot should respond with 'Good morning'.

Please tell me how do i make the bot respond to a message that has one of the elements in the array.
I am fairly new to JavaScript.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221909/discussion-on-question-by-hons-is-it-possible-to-make-the-bot-respond-to-a-messa).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code I suggested in the comments would work (not sure what you're saying doesn't work about it) - but it has a flaw

If `greetings` were something "I have a lot of phlegm" - it would match with `gm`

so lets try another way

```
function fn(keywords, target) {
    const res = keywords.map(s => new RegExp(`\\b${s}\\b`));
    return res.some(re => target.match(re));
}

client.on('message', message =>{

    if (message.author.bot) return;

    const fixgreet = message.content.slice();
    const greetings = fixgreet.toLowerCase();
    const gnvars = fs.readFileSync('./commands/urls/gn.txt').toString('utf-8');
    const gnraw = gnvars.split('\n');

    if (fn(gnraw, greetings)) {
        client.responds.get('gn').execute(message, fixgreet);
    }
```

so .. `fn` returns a boolean, that is true if one of the `gnraw` values is found in the `greetings` string

Comment: Okay thank you, I'll try it. and ill make sure to really learn it.

Comment: Ah sorry, I just found out the problem, apparently the array from the TEXT file isn't proper, i tested it with a normal array without extracting from another file. and it works. Thank you im really sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: Not a waste of time @Hons

Comment: Ah okay then... I am sure that this question would be useful somehow to starters.

Comment: @Hons - searching for one of a number of possible strings in a string is not uncommon - writing this answer has actually triggered me to rewrite some code (written before `array` had a `some` method) - so, win win